# Using JavaScript to dynamically resize images based on height of window/viewport

Tags: javascript, image, layout, resize, fluid

I'm trying to design a website for a photographer that will resize the height of images and thumbnails so that they fit the user's window size. This is the first time I have attempted a fluid layout rather than a fixed width one.

The images need to be resized based on the height of the browser, and must maintain aspect ratio.

To get a clearer idea of what my intention is, you can see the two designs i have (very much work in progress

http://annmariegrant.com/test1 (this design will have two or three rows of thumbnails, which will need to be resized based on the height of the window)

http://annmariegrant.com/test2 (this design will just have one row of images (a filmstrip), again, resized to fit the height of the window).

So far I just have a little test that access the .width DOM element of an image and changes it, but I just can't seem to get it to work properly, and am somewhat out of my depth, as I am sorta learning JavaScript on the fly here!

I hope I have provided enough detail for you to be able to help. Your responses will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just a small tip, to avoid the small bounce of the thumbnails when in hover, give them a transparent border of the same size as of the one in hover. This should do it:
.sc_menu a img {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother. Use CSS instead. Set the width of the img to be 100% so it will always scale to max available width of the container which should also not have a width set but you can set a max and min width. This why when the screen is resized (or viewed on a different device) the image is scaled by the browser to be as large as it can be. No JS required.

Comment: @Jaguar this might work but you'll have to have the images in a fluid container (having it's height at a percent as well).

Answer (score 0):

You want to recalculate the size of your images when window resizes. To do this, you need to put your JavasScript in the window resize event

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
}
```

In there you can recalculate the height and update your css style.